# Positive sinus on given points

Tags: trigonometry

I have $N$ points:

$x_1, \dots, x_N $

How to prove that there exists $\alpha$ such that

$\sin (\alpha x_i) > 0 \quad \forall i \ \in \{1,\dots,N\}$

Comment: There must be some condition on the $x_k$, otherwise such an $\alpha$ need not exist.

Comment: @DanielFischer of course, all x are non-zero and non - symmetric (with different absolute values)

Comment: @DanielFischer and user1761982 there must be more conditions, take e.g. $N=2$ and $x_2=-x_1$, then you have always $\sin(\alpha x_1)=-\sin(\alpha x_2),\forall\alpha$.

Comment: @flonk Yes, as i said, all x are with different absolute values, so there are no pairs like $x_i = - x_j$

Answer (score 0):

Like each $x_i$ is possible to be write as a element between $0$ and $2\pi$ (in order to represent the same function of $sin$) we can assume that are positives and take $$\alpha=\frac{\pi}{2max\{x_1,...,x_n\}}$$. 
If what you want to prove that with elements of diferent sign and don't think is possible.

Comment: Elements with different signs is a main problem, but i think that it is possible to solve it.